# ListView not setting initial selected row

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

My listview adapter is not setting the initial selected row.

I pull a currently selected truck key. Then I pull a list of possible truck keys. I compare the selected Key to the list of possible keys and if there is a match I set it to selected.

If I touch a row it becomes highlighted. But I want it to highlight the selected key automatically on load.

I have tried calling *`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`* in various places after the data is loaded but nothing seems to work.

***Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?***

Some console output to show the if statement is firing properly.

** Some console output**

> Curent positions key: 1010 truck: 116     - Selected Key: 1014
>
> Curent positions key: 1014 truck: 12355  - Selected Key: 1014  MATCH FOUND
>
> Curent positions key: 1020 truck: 16      - Selected Key: 1014
>
> Curent positions key: 1015 truck: 186     - Selected Key: 1014

**My Adapter:**

```
public class TruckAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final ArrayList mArrayList;

        public TruckAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> map) {
            mArrayList = map;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
            return (HashMap<String, String>) mArrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_truck, parent, false);
            }

            HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);

            TextView truckname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTruckName);
            truckname.setText(item.get("TRUCK").toString());


            if (Integer.parseInt(item.get("KEY")) == selectedTruckKey) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Curent positions key: " +Integer.parseInt(item.get("KEY")) + " truck: " + item.get("TRUCK")+ "  - Selected Key: "+ selectedTruckKey + " MATCH FOUND");
                convertView.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Curent positions key: " +Integer.parseInt(item.get("KEY")) + " truck: " + item.get("TRUCK")+ "  - Selected Key: "+ selectedTruckKey );
            }


            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

**My XML**

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lvTrucks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="@color/LIGHT_YELLOW"  />
```

**My Row Item XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTruckName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="45dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/COLOR_TXI_GREY"
        android:text="Name"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where do you set selectedTruckKey value?

Comment: I do a JSON request, get the selected key, then populate list view. It takes place before the listview is given data.